# How to fix a viewcontroller's rotation?

Tags: objective-c, uiviewcontroller, rotation, uiimagepickercontroller

My app uses landscape only. I fixed it via .plist's Supported interface orientations.

However, I need to use UIImagePickerController, and it only supports portrait mode. How can I rotate my app's rotation to portrait in a specific viewcontroller?

Any tips will be very helpful! Ty!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the blog post [iPhone programming: How to force your app to run in landscape mode](http://blog.typpz.com/2010/02/12/iphone-programming-how-to-force-your-app-to-run-in-landscape-mode/).

Answer (score 0):

ColinE, Do you mean that I should set as below?

All other viewControllers

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation 
{ 
    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight || UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft); 
}
```

and set the portarit page

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation 
{ 
    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait); 
}
```